# Facebook: any faster alternative to Like Button Event?

Tags: javascript, jquery, facebook, dom, facebook-like

I'm looking for a faster alternative to know when someone hit the like button on my site. Currently I'm using the Event.subscribe('edge.create') to get notified, but the response is sent about 3-4 seconds after the user hit the Like button.

Does anyone has an idea for a faster (ideally instant) solution?

I noticed that the second I hit the button the Comment box is popping under the Like Button, so maybe there is a way to use it as a trigger for an event.

Obviously the fact that the button is in an iFrame is the most challenging issue here.

Answer (score 3):

> Obviously the fact that the button is in an iFrame is the most challenging issue here.

That’s not a *challenging* issue – that’s an issue that won’t let you do **anything** about it.

The *same origin policy* prevents you from interacting with the iframe’s content from your scripts. Facebook does some cross-domain communication in the background … and that’s **why** it takes a little time before the event you registered fires.

I don’t see any way of working around that, sorry.

Comment: The second you click on the Like button, the Comment box is opened as default which well exceed the boundaries of the original Likebox iFrame. Maybe there is a way to Listen to that event (though I believe the commend box is in its own iFrame). Maybe there is an option to listen to a click inside the iFrame (like getting the current coordinates of the iFrame and that of the mouse cursor and track the click if it happened in pre-defined coordinates. Though a click isn't a guarantee the user actually Liked the page, its good enough for my needs.